# how to port javascript web application to iOS application?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, web

I have a web app how can I port it to iOS app? The app should be seemed native for the iOS.
The web app is written in Javascript.

Comment: This is very vague. What have you tried? There are some directions to go for you. Check out UI kits like http://www.idangero.us/framework7 or frameworks like PhoneGap.

Comment: I did search in google and came up with much solutions... So wanted to confirm from this forum. And as I dint find any question here regarding this thought of posting one! Anyways, thanks for suggesting googling Tilwin Joy!!

Comment: @crusader welcome among us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create iOS apps using one of this two platforms:

[AppAccelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/appcelerator-platform/)  or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). (however I would suggest to use PhoneGap)

Comment: I agree, you will obviously need to do a bit of work but if you have most of the js then this will be the best route to go.